# Where does the expression 'Kick the Bucket' come from?

Tags: etymology, expressions, phrase-origin

The expression to "kick the bucket", meaning to die, doesn't quite make sense when you stop and try to apply it literally to what it means.

So where does the expression come from? The historical context of an expression often explains how the expression links to what it means.

Comment: There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kick_the_bucket) which goes into the subject in some detail.

Comment: There are a lot of good sources that provide information about its origin: https://www.google.it/search?q=kick+the+bucket+origin&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=kick+the+bucket+origin+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.7774j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Comes from a scene early in [It's a Mad Mad  Mad Mad World](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057193/?ref_=nv_sr_1) where, as a person injured in an auto accident dies, he reflexively [strikes a bucket with his leg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w00Kab17aeI).  (OK, maybe it isn't the *very first* use of the expression, but it's a good one.)

Comment: John Hotten's _Dictionary of  Modern Slang, Cant, and Vulgar Words_, second edition (1860) has an interesting theory of the origin in his entry for "[kick the bucket](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kfo3AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA163&dq=%22E.+S.+Taylor%22+Norfolk+Bucket&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixmvK2g6jSAhUG5WMKHXL5AugQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22E.%20S.%20Taylor%22%20Norfolk%20Bucket&f=false)." Basically he finds early use of it in a regional glossary from Norfolk.

Comment: ...However, Hotten's source for the expression, Robert Forby,  [_The Vocabulary of East Anglia_](https://books.google.com/books?id=2BFJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%221.+Phr+to+kick+the+bucket%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizxqSF8vXTAhWK5lQKHbUuA2oQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%221.%20Phr%20to%20kick%20the%20bucket%22&f=false), volume 2 (1830), doesn't confirm the gloss that Hotten gives—and in fact offers a second expression that (Forby says) is likewise "fit only for the mouths of rude, unfeeling boors": "to kick stiff." As Hotten says, the explanation comes as an ms annotation by a third researcher.

Comment: @WS2 Interestingly the 'kickeraboo' word from the wikipedia entry appears in the Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue as 'KICKERAPOO. Dead. NEGRO WORD.'. It's the next entry after 'kick the bucket' so if they are related, they were also concurrent.

Comment: @HotLicks the OED has an entry from 1889. *G. Allen Tents of Shem I. x. 166   Sir Arthur..will do the right thing in the end before he kicks the bucket.*

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah, but I bet you can't find a Youtube clip for that.

Comment: Existing online treatments are insufficient to explain the origin of the phrase.